# Chrome app on Smart TVs

Tags: google-chrome, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

In need of a common app for all Smart TVs that occupies full screen on boot.

Is chrome browser supported by most or all Smart TVs, so that I can launch a chrome app onboot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome browser is not a standard install on smart TV. Remember there is no "standard" for a smart TV. Manufacturers can decide to have the whole stack with their software.

And they control what appears on the store. I can't see any app Chrome or otherwise that would be gives control of any smart TV on boot, never mind let your app take control via Chrome

Comment: All famous smart TV OS that have a app store concept would most likely have chrome available as one of their apps, right ?

Comment: And they control what appears on the store. I can't see any app Chrome or otherwise that would be gives control of any smart TV on boot

Answer (score 1):

You can use some multiplatform solution, which runs in Chrome browser or some TVs Samsung, LG, Sony, Philips,...

But each app requires some additional configuration files and upload it on each platform store.